# save login details or session on php for a mobile app

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, webview

i have built a small web app using PHP Codeigniter and converted it to and android and ios app using the webview. The problem is that when the user opens the app and logins and surf a bit and closes the app, and when he opens it again goes back to the login page, instead of redirecting to the dashboard (unless he has logged out).

For the login and authentication i have used Ion Auth.

When i contacted the guy who made the app he told me that i need to save the ion auth session and/or login details in a cookie so next time when the app is opened it will login automatically. This must be done on the web app not on android or ios app.

Can someone please explain me how this can be done in php?

Comment: Hi there, I work with CodeIgniter since few years and have made one Android native App (Java), I recommend you using a regular website ~or~ making an App, I don't know what "...and converted it to and android and ios app using the webview" means, sorry :-( Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the IOS webview works, but I would see two possible solutions for your problem.

1. Increase the cookie expiration date
2. If webview does not keep the cookies between sessions, you would then need to save the cookie locally (not php, using swift, java or other similar mobile dev), and reinsert it in your webview each session.